# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Hours' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Hours' to data type int. This is my query:

```
Sum(Cast(Cast(DATEDIFF(HH, ld_time_tracker_start_time,
    fld_time_tracker_end_time)%3600/60 As int) +' Hours'+ 
Cast(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ld_time_tracker_start_time,
 fld_time_tracker_end_time)As int )+'Minutes' As Int)) 
As [Time Spent(In hrs)]
```

I modified the above Code To:

```
+Cast('Hours' As Int)
+Covert(int,'Hours')
```

... and got the error message:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' Hours' to data
>   type int

Answer (score 2):

This is not clear what output is needed. 
You are trying to convert text strings to int. This obviously does not work. Besides this type of formatting might fit better outside of SQL Server.

If you want something like `5 Hours 15 Minutes` you can try this query:

```
[Time Spent(In hrs)] =
    CAST(
        SUM(
            DATEDIFF(hour, ld_time_tracker_start_time, ld_time_tracker_end_time)                     
        )
    as varchar(10))
    +' Hours '+ 
    CAST(
        SUM(
            DATEDIFF(minute, ld_time_tracker_start_time, ld_time_tracker_end_time) % 60       
        )
    as varchar(10))
+' Minutes'
```

Note that I have replaced `HH` by `hour`. This is easier to read and understand and it avoid mistakes. See [DATEDIFF (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms189794(v=sql.120).aspx).